# Using np.where to create a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to create number of days based on two variables. If the units are in week, multiply the `nums` by 7, if by month by 12 and 365 if by year. Am unable to achieve this...any leads??

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nums = [2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 11, 1, 1]
units = ['days', 'weeks', 'year', 'month', 'days', 'weeks', 'years', 'months', 'day', 'week']


df = pd.DataFrame({'nums': nums,
                  'units': units})

df

def convert_days(var1,var2,var3):
    df[var3]= np.where((df[var1]=='weeks', df[var2]*7, df[var2]))
    return df


convert_days('units', 'nums', 'test')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
dmap = {'days?': 1, 'weeks?': 7, 'months?': 12, 'years?': 365}
df['days'] = df['nums'] * df['units'].replace(dmap, regex=True)
print(df)

# Output
   nums   units  days
0     2    days     2
1     3   weeks    21
2     4    year  1460
3     1   month    12
4     4    days     4
5     2   weeks    14
6     4   years  1460
7    11  months   132
8     1     day     1
9     1    week     7
```

Note: the `s?` is to take into account the plural form (ends with 's' or not)

Comment: Interesting! It did not appear to me that I could use replace...

Comment: You can also use `map` but you should have exact match (year vs years, day vs days, etc). So if you need to use a regex, `replace` is better.